# GSI_Logger Given origin is not allowed in Electron + React application

Tags: reactjs, typescript, electron, google-drive-api, google-oauth

Being kinda new to React and everything clientside related, I am trying to build a Electron application with React.
At this point I can't tell if that's a good idea, but I wanted to try it.

Currently it works fine (see [Github](https://github.com/Urr4/electron-archive)).

However I now wanted to add `@react-oauth/google` to give users the option to sign into their Google Account to allow the application to access their google drive and I'm struggling with that.
See the [testing_auth_2 branch](https://github.com/Urr4/electron-archive/tree/testing_auth_2) for that.

I enabled the drive-api in GCP and created credentials for a web application, adding http://localhost and http://localhost:3000 as authorised Javascript origins.
Now it works, but only when I start it as a webpage (`npm start` in my Github)
Starting it as an electron app failes, probably because electron doesnt run under localhost somehow (`npm run electron:dev` in my github code).
I tried creating Desktop and ios credentials since those dont ned authorised origins but the error persists.

Steps to recreate:
Enable drive api and create credentials in GCP
clone git@github.com:Urr4/electron-archive.git
checkout testing_auth_2 branch
Replace XXX in index.tsx with the client_id
The Google login should work using `npm start`, but not using `npm run electron:dev`

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Do you know if the electro app generates an specific URI that can be added over the GCP project ?

Comment: I couldn't find anything about that